# replace div with loading.gif before page loads, wait 3 seconds, remove loading gif and show div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a select drop down that is dynamically built, so I have a setTimeout to change the selected option after 3 seconds, so the select can load first and then I can change it. But I want to hide the select and show a loading gif, and after the 3 seconds show the select with the option I forced it to show.

Here's a jsfiddle showing how far I got: https://jsfiddle.net/88ot9vya/1/

I'm using the setTimeout to change it after 3 seconds which works perfect:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#txtShipAddress>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
}, 3000);
```

How do I add a loading gif before hand, run the setTimeout, then show it and hide and loading gif? Here's an example gif doesn't matter what's used:
https://media.giphy.com/media/TkXCbTx9gfUJi/giphy.gif

Comment: why not just use a document ready event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an img tag and hide the select initially.

https://jsfiddle.net/88ot9vya/2/

The gif isn't loading in the fiddle but it loads the image then the select.

```html
<select name="txtShipAddress" id="txtShipAddress" style="display:none;">
    <option value="-2">Please Choose One</option>
    <option value="115599">#1</option>    
    <option value="141044">#2</option>    
    <option value="143936">#3</option>    
    <option value="143414">#4</option>    
    <option value="-1" selected>Free Form Address</option>
</select>
<img id="giffy-poo"  src="https://giphy.com/gifs/loading-TkXCbTx9gfUJi?utm_source=media-link&utm_medium=landing&utm_campaign=Media%20Links&utm_term=https://www.google.com/" />
```

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#txtShipAddress>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
    $('#giffy-poo').hide()
    $('select').show()
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a very similar structure to @Kosch

my answer is using a [`document ready event handler`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to make sure that the select is there first before it tries to bring up the script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtShipAddress').hide();
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('#txtShipAddress>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
      $('#txtShipAddress').show();
      $('#loader').hide();
  }, 3000);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="txtShipAddress" id="txtShipAddress" >
    <option value="-2">Please Choose One</option>
    <option value="115599">#1</option>    
    <option value="141044">#2</option>    
    <option value="143936">#3</option>    
    <option value="143414">#4</option>    
    <option value="-1" selected>Free Form Address</option>
</select>
<img id="loader"  src="https://media.giphy.com/media/nZQIwSpCXFweQ/giphy.gif" />
```